# Function returning data from db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a newbie to node js and I am using mongoose for my models.

I have a function namde check which has a isNameThere function which receives name string as parameter in it. It checks the Db and looks for the name string which is provided if user exist in this name this.isNameThere will return true

```
var check= function()
{   

  this.nameIsThere = false;

  this.isNameThere= function(name){

  userModel.find({firstname: name},function(err,result){

                if(result)
                {
                    this.nameIsThere= true;
                }

               })

 return this.nameIsThere;  
 }
 }
```

Even if the name exist as you guess the code above will return **false** because the nature of asynchronous programming. Is there a way to execute the **return isNameThere** after **userModel.find** executes. Or any other solution for this situation. Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

Careful with the semicolons, you forgot some. It´s also good practice in JavaScript to place opening brackets right next to the function header and not in the next line.

You can encapsulate the DB call in a function like this:

```
function checkForName (callback) {
    userModel.find({firstname: name}, callback);
}

checkForName(function (err, result) {
    if (result) {
        nameIsThere = true;
        //do something else
        ...
    }
});
```

After all, it IS anychronous, so you will not get any synchronous return value.

There´s also another way: Promises. Some libraries for you to check out:

- https://github.com/caolan/async
- https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Thanks for reply, In my question isNameThere is a function and i am calling this function from other file and I expect that isName there to return back a true/false result back. The main thing that I want to do is to execute return of isNameThere after the userMode.find finishes its operation and checks that if the name exists or not. I need to return true or false that is my point.

Comment: that is not how it works, there is no synchronous way. the only thing you can do is use a callback function as parameter for the "isNameThere" function (see my code) and call that function when you got a result.